# Running NPM mapbox-map-image-export

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

Im new to NPM/Node and am trying to run a seeingly simple command but am having trouble.

Im using VS Code and have used the terminal to clone the GIT repo. Then 'npm install'.

I am trying to run the command in the documentation 'export MAPBOX_TOKEN=YOUR_MAPBOX_API_PUBLIC_TOKEN'

Based on the instructions on the NPM page https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox-map-image-export

To do this I type in 'node' then the command above. However I just get three dots appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unix systems, `export` is a Shell built-in command used to mark a variable for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands. The Windows (MS-DOS) equivalent command is `set`.

So, to set the Mapbox token in Windows, just open a command prompt and execute:

```
set MAPBOX_TOKEN=YOUR_MAPBOX_API_PUBLIC_TOKEN
```

You can then run mapbox-map-image-export in the same command prompt session, like this:

```
export-map mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9 -w=11in -h=8.5in -b=-7.1354,57.9095,-6.1357,58.516 -t=%MAPBOX_TOKEN% -o=lewis.png
```

Note that in Windows, %NAME% is used to get a variable value, so it's `%MAPBOX_TOKEN%` (and not `$MAPBOX_TOKEN`).

You can also specify the Mapbox token directly in the `export-map` command, without setting an environment variable, e.g.:

```
export-map mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9 -w=11in -h=8.5in -b=-7.1354,57.9095,-6.1357,58.516 -t=YOUR_MAPBOX_API_PUBLIC_TOKEN -o=lewis.png
```

Comment: My OS is win 10. I am trying exact same commands but it is not working for me - no errors, no file generated. I know my token is valid because I am using it in a different project.

Comment: @shobhitvaish: let's figure this out! Can you please provide more info, e.g. node version, how you installed the package, command line you are running, etc.? I assume you are running it in Command Prompt, right?

Comment: @DiegoColantoni Thanks for your response! Details: Node version: **8.9.4**, command **npm install mapbox-map-image-export -g**, Command prompt: Tried both windows command prompt and nodejs command prompt

Comment: @shobhitvaish: it's strange that you don't get any error message... Have you tried running it directly from its location? Mine is located at `C:\Users\diego\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mapbox-map-image-export`. cd into it, and try to run: `node cmd.js mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9 -w=11in -h=8.5in -b=-7.1354,57.9095,-6.1357,58.516 -t=YOUR_MAPBOX_API_PUBLIC_TOKEN -o=lewis.png`. Do you get any errors?

Comment: @DiegoColantoni No errors and again no file generated. I am looking for the file at this path: C:\Users\shobhitvaish\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mapbox-map-image-export

Comment: @shobhitvaish: it's really strange that is not returning any errors... Can you please edit the cmd.js file, and add a `console.log('logging')` statement under the comment at the top? Then run `node cmd.js -b=-7.1354,57.9095,-6.1357,58.516`. You should see a `logging` message, followed by an error complaining that you haven't provided the API token. In this way, we'll be sure that we are actually running it.

Comment: @DiegoColantoni Yes without token I get this error AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing --token (must pass a valid Mapbox API token)

Comment: @shobhitvaish: good! At least now we know that the script is being invoked. Maybe Electron is dying? Unfortunately you might have to do some debugging. The easiest thing to do is putting some `console.log` statements in `main.js` and follow the execution of the script. For example, you can check that the Electron window is being created (btw, you can show the window by setting: `win = new BrowserWindow({show: true})`). As far as I understood, `cmd.js` calls `main.js` which starts Electron and opens `index.html`. At that point `renderer.js` is invoked.

Comment: @DiegoColantoni Thanks for your guidance so far! It never hits createWindow() function in main.js - looks like Electron is dying. I have tried reinstalling but no luck. :(

Comment: It looked like the issue was passing the height argument as `-h`. For some reason, the Electron child process failed to be spawned. Specifying the height with the `--height` flag solved the problem.

Comment: @DiegoColantoni Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: @DiegoColantoni I want to talk to you about a project. Please let me know the best way to reach out to you. My skype is shobhitvaish@yahoo.com

Comment: @shobhitvaish, hi, did you get my email?

Answer (score 0):

The command (`export MAPBOX_TOKEN=YOUR_MAPBOX_API_PUBLIC_TOKEN`) you saw in the documentation aims at being run in a shell, not the node REPL.

Its job is to configure the token which can then be used by this package CLI. Technically it means:

> Define an environment variable accessible to all the upcoming processes named MAPBOX_TOKEN with the value YOUR_MAPBOX_API_PUBLIC_TOKEN.

Executing it in a shell will enable the [`export-map`](https://github.com/digidem/mapbox-map-image-export/blob/ad45530780406d08561e090f3e3ccb647a9704e9/package.json#L7) command to grab it through [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env).

Comment: I have run the commmand in the shell and I still have no joy. I get 'export' is not recognized as a internal or external command.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Im on Windows 7